# (oracle) insert in stored procedure very slow compared to insert run manually

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I run an insert from Oracle sql tool that selects about 100.000 rows from various  tables and inserts them in another table at different databsae and this ends in 3 mins.
I try the same query inside a stored procedure or PLSQL in oracle and we run for about 2 hours. For information i use Source Oracle 11g and the destination Oracle 10g

Stored Procedure (takes about 2 hour per store):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MGS.TRANSFER_DATA(a_date in varchar2) -- yyyymmdd
BEGIN
 BEGIN
 FOR xx IN(
  SELECT STR_CD FROM MGS.STORE ORDER BY STR_CD ASC
 ) LOOP
  CALL_LOG(xx.STR_CD,a_date,sysdate,"START INSERT");
  INSERT INTO STOCK@BBS
  SELECT
   STR_CD, STK.DT, PROD_CD, QTY, ORDER_QTY, ORDER_QTY
  FROM
   MGS.STOCK STK, MGS.SALE SAL
   WHERE STK.STR_CD = xx.STR
   AND STK.STR_CD = SAL.STR_CD(+)
   AND STK.PROD_CD = SAL.PROD_CD(+)
   AND STK.DT = SAL.DT(+)
   AND STK.DT = a_date;
 CALL_LOG(xx.STR_CD,a_date,sysdate,"INSERT SUCESSFULL");
END LOOP;
END;
```

END TRANSFER_DATA;

I tried query for 1 store (just take 3 minute):

```
INSERT INTO STOCK@BBS
SELECT
 STR_CD, STK.DT, PROD_CD, QTY, ORDER_QTY, ORDER_QTY
FROM
 MGS.STOCK STK, MGS.SALE SAL
 WHERE STK.STR_CD = 'STORE01'
 AND STK.STR_CD = SAL.STR_CD(+)
 AND STK.PROD_CD = SAL.PROD_CD(+)
 AND STK.DT= SAL.DT(+)
 AND STK.DT= '20120801'; -- yyyymmdd
```

Comment: Presumably there are indexes on the STOCK table. Are you able to disable then rebuild these? Large inserts require the index information to be updated for each record which can be slow. Always better to disable/drop them if you can then enable/create them later.

Comment: Use trace to see the query plan, I suspect it may be quite different for the PL/SQL vs for the SQL (which uses hard-coded literals for one thing).  I have a suspicion it may work better if you create the procedure on the BBS side so that it "pulls" rather than "pushes", but am not in a position to verify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't got the answer why the query in plsql become slowly, but i have solution bellow :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MGS.TRANSFER_DATA(a_date in varchar2) -- yyyymmdd
BEGIN
 BEGIN
 FOR xx IN(
  SELECT STR_CD FROM MGS.STORE ORDER BY STR_CD ASC
 ) LOOP
  CALL_LOG(xx.STR_CD,a_date,sysdate,"START INSERT");
  execute immediate '
  INSERT INTO STOCK@BBS
  SELECT
   STR_CD, STK.DT, PROD_CD, QTY, ORDER_QTY, ORDER_QTY
  FROM
   MGS.STOCK STK, MGS.SALE SAL
   WHERE STK.STR_CD = ''' || xx.STR || '''
   AND STK.STR_CD = SAL.STR_CD(+)
   AND STK.PROD_CD = SAL.PROD_CD(+)
   AND STK.DT = SAL.DT(+)
   AND STK.DT = ''' || a_date || '''
 ';
 CALL_LOG(xx.STR_CD,a_date,sysdate,"INSERT SUCESSFULL");
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection if you do this.  The performance is likely improved because you have given Oracle actual literal values rather than bind variables.  More information allowed it to create a better plan (at the cost of spending more time creating plans).

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that the plan being generated for the query in the procedure differs significantly from the plan generated for the stand-alone query.  In the stand-alone version you've got constants in there which allow the optimizer to make some good assumptions.  Without the constants the optimizer has less to go on and is thus probably make some different decisions.  Try this:

Get the execution plan for the stand-alone query.

Get the execution plan for the following (which just replaces your loop with a subquery refactoring clause):

```
WITH xx AS (SELECT STR_CD, '20120801' AS A_DATE
              FROM MGS.STORE ORDER BY STR_CD ASC)
  SELECT STR_CD, "DATE", PROD_CD, QTY, ORDER_QTY, ORDER_QTY
    FROM MGS.STOCK STK, MGS.SALE SAL
    WHERE STK.STR_CD = xx.STR AND
          STK.STR_CD = SAL.STR_CD(+) AND
          STK.PROD_CD = SAL.PROD_CD(+) AND
          STK."DATE" = SAL."DATE"(+) AND
          STK."DATE" = xx.A_DATE
```

(Note that I had to double-quote the columns named `DATE`.  I'm surprised you didn't encounter this).  Compare the plans.  The second plan is obviously going to differ from the first due to the presence of the subquery factoring clause, but try to compare the matching elements.  In particular look for elements where the first query is using an index while the second is performing a full table scan.

Add hints as necessary to the second query to get its plan to match the first as closely as possible.

The other possibility, which I consider unlikely, is that the logging calls are where the time is being spent.  For grins you might try commenting the logging out to see if that has an effect (which I wouldn't expect, but life has thus far been filled with things I didn't expect :-).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start all these inserts in parallel by dbms_job for each store. May be it permits to acheive  the same performance as conventional sql. I think dbms_parallel_execute could help you as well, please refer to http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2.php